# Skobbler map clustering

Tags: ios, skmaps

I'm trying to figure out how I can use pin clustering with SKMapView and SKAnnotation?I see that there is SKPOICluster, but I'm not sure there is a way to Use it with SKAnnotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no clustering support for SKAnnotations (you will have to implement yourself the logic for choosing which annotations are visible at each zoom level).

**Note:** clustering support for SKAnnotations is work in progress

The SKPoiCluster is to be used with [SKMapPoi](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.1.0/Classes/SKMapPOI.html). (SKMapPoi offers clustering support) The tradeoff for SKMapPoi is that the icons that can be used are rather limited - sprites from a png file, so if you want to modify an icon you need to modify the png file.